# How to copy back to host package-lock.json/yarn.lock after install dependencies inside docker container?

Tags: node.js, git, docker, yarnpkg, yarn-lock.json

I'm using Docker containers to run my CRA application. I use 2 different DockerFile, one for running CRA in development and one to generate the build. During the step of installing dependencies:

```
FROM node:15.5.0-alpine3.10

USER node

RUN mkdir /home/node/code
WORKDIR /home/node/code

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

ENV PATH /home/node/code/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

CMD yarn start
```

I need to copy my updated yarn.lock file (or package-lock.json file is using NPM) back to host after the container generate the new version of the file.

I had search the solution everywhere, but I didn't find anything to resolve this problem.

Comment: I'd recommend doing things in the opposite order: run `yarn upgrade` on your host, run unit tests, and then run `docker build` to build a new image.  (Shouldn't that Dockerfile have a `COPY . .` line to copy the application into the image?)

Answer (score 1):

[docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/), for example `docker cp [running container id]:/home/node/code/yarn.lock yarn.lock`. You can also use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) rather than copying things in and out.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled my way here,
a possible solution is to use:

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

Answer (score 0):

I solved it moving it into a folder and syncing it using a volume (examples include only relevant code for this case).

File `./Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:12-alpine

# Copy all files inside sync-package-lock into workdir of docker 
COPY sync-package-lock ./

# If package-lock.json is not found in previous step, it will be created in the following npm install
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# Following entrypoint will copy the package-lock.json to the sync volume
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]
CMD [ "npm", "run", "serve" ]
```

File `./docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# copy package-lock.json to the shared volume "sync-package-lock" so its synced between host and container
cp -a /app/package-lock.json /app/sync-package-lock/

echo "Finised docker-entrypoint.sh"

# Finish entrypoint. Run the CMD
exec "$@"
```

File `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    volumes:
        - "../backend/sync-package-lock:/app/sync-package-lock"
```